# Autoload.php composer. Не подгружается Class

Tags: php, composer, autoload

У меня не получается загрузить приватную библиотку в автозагрузчик.
Ошибка, что неизвестный класс в index.php `SystemCoreMessage`.

После добавленя PSR-4 в composer.json я выполнил composer update.

Файловая структура:

```
- library/
    - internal/
        - scm/
            - src/
                - SystemCoreMessage.php
- public/
    - index.php
- composer.json
```

Composer:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SystemCoreMessage\\": "library/internal/scm/scr/"
        }
    }
}
```

Index:

```
<?php

require_once realpath(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

use SystemCoreMessage\SystemCoreMessage;

$sys_header = null;
$scm_header = null;
$scm = new SystemCoreMessage($sys_header, $scm_header);
```

SystemCoreMessage.php

```
<?php

namespace SystemCoreMessage;

class SystemCoreMessage {
  ...
}
```

Comment: В одном месте `src`, в другом `scr`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать `composer dump-autoload` для того, чтобы автолоадер обновил пути

Comment: Не помогло.
Сам путь у меня обновился после апдейта.
`'SystemCoreMessage\\' => array($baseDir . '/library/simbase/scm/scr'));`.